# SharePoint 2013 User profile service application Database's

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have been investigation some odd behavior on my SharePoint environment, I think I have found the cause of the issue but need a little help in understanding it and how to fix it.

I built my SharePoint environment in a isolated network, 1 SharePoint 2013 server and 1 SQL 2012 server, when completed I migrated it to production via VMware this was about 3 months ago so luckily I had a copy of the original SharePoint in an original functional state.

I have now loaded up that functional copy to try and deduce what is causing the errors and issues but it cant be used for production due to the massive gap of 3 months and the amount of data and files placed on it since then.

When I compare settings they match, IIS settings, Web.config's and internal SharePoint settings via central admin, but still one works and one doesn't.

I then tried taking a copy of production SQL 2012 server and pairing it with my old functional SharePoint 2013 server and after some playing I got them to talk to each other but it still never worked, I got the same errors.

The errors only went away when I was using the original (3 month old) SQLDB server.

So I narrowed it down to an issue with the SQL server: When I compared the database's side by side I notice some potentially significant differences. Can someone explain what I need to do to sort out the user profile service application or how I can resolve it?

This is the working SQL server DB list:

[image: working sql server]

And here is the one with the errors on it:

[image: Working but with the errors and problems]

Comment: could you please tell us, which error you are seeing? in which environment production or your development? what is the issue with User profile? when you said functional copy of sharepoint production, are you talking about snapshot of sharepoint?

Comment: According to the screenshots, both situations have completely different user profile service application databases. I suppose your service application was rebuilt at one time with other databases. Snapshotting SharePoint is not supported, but if you did - did you revert to snapshot for the SQL Server too? I'm guessing SharePoint & SQL are out of sync.

Comment: The main error I am getting is a claims authentication error In the uls logs failed to issue a security token, error 8306 and also excel web app errors saying something went wrong please try again later on any excel web apps I try to create I get these on the production environment but don't get them on the old environment. Yes I used snapshots at the time I now have a more robust system in place but it does look like they are out sync, what can I do to add the missing databases to my production environment the user profile service application. Many thanks Bpdzenith